# Diagonal matrix factored into a product of two non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

> Given diagonal $n \times n$ matrix $D$, find $n \times m$ matrix $U$ and $m \times n$ matrix $V$ such that $$U V = D$$

---

I am trying to apply the Woodbury matrix identity. I am inverting $(A+UV)$, where the update to the matrix $A$ is a diagonal matrix. Thus, $UV$ is a diagonal matrix. I would like to be able to define the matrix $U$ and $V$ such that I can place elements at any position along the diagonal of the product $UV$. In other words, if I want to place a certain value, say a, on the diagonal say at row $3$ column $3$, what are the matrices $U$ and $V$. The diagonal of the product of $UV$ will have many zeros and a few particular non-zero values placed at desired locations along the diagonal. For example, what is $U$ and $V$ to generate a diagonal matrix with the following diagonal ($0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0$), or ($1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0$)? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why does U and V have to be non-square?  Are either of these matrices known ahead of time?  Cant you just find *any* square U and V that satisfy the equation, then tack on the appropriate number of 0 rows and columns?  Or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: The problem is very similar to: I have a dense matrix A and its corresponding inverse A−1. The Woodbury matrix identity states:

(A+UCV)−1=A−1−A−1U(C−1+VA−1U)−1VA−1
I wish to perform small updates to the diagonal of A and compute corresponding A−1. The updates can actually be described as a constant k multiplying an identity matrix: kI and in my case U=VT where V is a tall matrix with just ones and zeros that selects the desired diagonal positions of A to modify.

Comment: You can find the original post referenced above here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10253/updating-matrix-diagonal-with-woodbury-matrix-identity-and-maintaining-numerical

Comment: I just need to identify the matrices U and V that allow an update to the diagonal of kI as in the above reference

Comment: Are you still interested in this problem? Are the diagonal entries of $D$ positive?